# Drupal Commerce - Database location of Shipping information

Tags: commerce

I am attempting to migrate the data located on the /admin/commerce/orders page of Drupal Commerce to a custom website that I have created. I am trying to use phpMyAdmin to locate and export any relevant database information in the Drupal database. I have found that the order id/email/timestamp are located in the commerce_order table in the Drupal database. However, I can't find the location (table/table column) of the user's name and shipping information.

Does anyone have an idea of where I could find this information?

I am currently using Drupal 7.53 and Drupal Commerce 7.x-1.13.

Comment: Depending on your needs and how familiar you are with Drupal, it might be faster to make a view that shows all the info you need and then use [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) to get a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal's entity data isn't really meant to be exported directly from the database. Is there no way for you to build a PHP script that uses the Drupal API to load and export these entities instead? Or an existing module like Patrick suggests?

Otherwise, you're going to need to pull information from a variety of tables. Shipping information is stored on an order's shipping customer profile. These are linked to the order via a customer profile reference field (whose table should be field_data_commerce_customer_shipping). From there you can find the customer profile ID you'll need to search for in the address field data, matching the profile ID against the entity_id in the field_data_commerce_customer_address table.